# Caret function doesn't work well if the caret is at the last position

Tags: javascript, html

Following the code for get caret position (how many characters there are before the caret in a textarea) in IE8 and less:

```
function getIEtextareaCaret(el) {
    var start = 0,
    range = el.createTextRange(),
    range2 = document.selection.createRange().duplicate(),
    range2Bookmark = range2.getBookmark();
    range.moveToBookmark(range2Bookmark);
    while (range.moveStart('character' , -1) !== 0) {
    start++;
    }
    return start;
}
```

It's works well, but if the caret is at the last position (for example, if the textarea contains "abc", the caret is after the c) the function returns a wrong number like 1. How to solve it?

Comment: You are missing a `,` at the end of the `range2` line. And as a result, `range2Bookmark` becomes a global variable.

Comment: @kapa: Fixed, I was wrong to copy, but it's not the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered in [How to get caret position in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea).

If you use the code from the answer, you should get the correct offset (Checked in IE8 and Chrome):

```
function getCaret(el) { 
  if (el.selectionStart) { 
    return el.selectionStart; 
  } else if (document.selection) { 
    el.focus(); 

    var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
    if (r == null) { 
      return 0; 
    } 

    var re = el.createTextRange(), 
        rc = re.duplicate(); 
    re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark()); 
    rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re); 

    return rc.text.length; 
  }  
  return 0; 
}
```

Plus, this works in other browsers, too.